# Excel: How to collect data from a single cell and place it in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, copy-paste

I have a macro that does some calculations and then produces a result that appears in a single cell. When I run the macro again it produces another result in the same cell and so on. I wish to copy the data from that cell and place it in a table, let's say in cell B1. And then the next result in cell C1. And so on until I have a table of data.

Is there a simple way to do this?

And could I have the macro run (say) 100 times and each time copy the data in to the table as described above?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to modify your macro to include a loop that keeps track of the number of results and puts the output into the next available cell in the output table.  Read this [Tutorial About Loops in VBA](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-loops/).  Try to write some code and then, if you run into problems, edit this question to illustrate the problem you're having. It's always best to include the code that gives the error, and a screenshot of the results if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a super simple macro example:

```
Sub MaintainHistory()
    Dim s As String, n As Long, v As Variant
    v = Rnd()
    Range("A1") = v
    If Range("B1") = "" Then
        Range("B1") = v
    Else
        n = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("B" & n) = v
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but it records strange results. When I enter a whole number in cell A1 (say 4) and run the macro, 4 gets changed to a decimal (0.52...) and 'that' gets tabulated in B1. If I try again (with A1 = 4 again) it changes to a different decimal (0.76...) and tabulates it into cell B2, and so on.

Comment: That's because the macro generates a random number in line 3 and puts it in A1.  I think GS was just demonstrating how to fill a table, so you could add that part to your macro.  If you replace the 3rd and 4th lines with:
`v = Range("A1").Value`, this macro will take the value in A1 and put it in the next blank cell in column B.